# new array with values when call a constructor

Tags: solidity

```
    contract A  {
        function A(address[] _owners, uint _required) {
        }
    }

    contract B is A {
        function B()
          A(new address[](0),0)) { // Call something like that
        }
    }

    contract C is A {
       function C() 
         A([0x123],0) { // and like that
       }
    }
```

Is is possible to call a super constructor with an initialized array ?

Comment: It will be helpful to know what the successful contract will do. Too many problems with syntax and structure to intuit exact intent. Are you saying you want B & C to be able to set/get an array that resides in A, or are you saying you want B & C to have their own instances of an array that gets some initial values from A?

Comment: A use the array _owners an the variable _required to initialise the instance.
B would like to invoke the constructor of A to initialise the part A of B, with a defaults values.
C would like to do the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about you sneakily use a function of the yet to be deployed contract? I successfully tested this code in Browser Solidity. Note the use of a parameter too:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.2;

contract A  {
    address[] public owners;    
    function A(address[] _owners, uint _required) {
        owners = _owners;
    }
}

contract C is A {
   function C(uint size) 
     A(getInitialArray(size), 0) { // and like that
   }
   function getInitialArray(uint size) constant returns (address[] initial) {
       initial = new address[](size);
       initial[0] = 0x1234567890123456789012345678901234567890;
   }
}
```

That would be nuts in Java, but I think it is similar to using a `static` function in Java.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that sort of thing but we're limited to passing data in/out using only fixed length arguments. That can include a fixed length array. It often means breaking the problem down into a more granular approach.

Here's a way to organize the data and some one-liner functions that show data passed back and forth between A and an unlimited population of B. I had to guess about where the B come from, so A is a factory that makes B. A keeps track of the B it created. Whomever calls A.newB will be B's owner; a fairly common reason for passing information around like this.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.8;

contract A { // hub a.k.a. factory

    struct ContractStructs { // instance details
        address contractOwner;
    }

    mapping(address => ContractStructs) contractStructs; // instance details by key
    address[] private contractIndex; // list of keys

    address owner; // owns A for possible privileged access

    function A() {
        owner = msg.sender; // deployer is owner of the contract hub
    }

    function newB() returns(address newB) {
        B b = new B(msg.sender); // anyone can call this function. Their address will be passed to B constructor
        contractStructs[b].contractOwner = msg.sender; // details to struc
        contractIndex.push(b); // key to the index
        return b; // return contract address created
    }

    function getContractCount() constant returns(uint contractCount) {
        return contractIndex.length; // number of contracts in the list
    }

    function getContractAtIndex(uint index) constant returns(address contractAddress) {
        return contractIndex[index]; // get contract address by row
    }

    function getContractOwner(address contractAddress) constant returns(address contractOwner) {
        return contractStructs[contractAddress].contractOwner; // get contract owner by contract address
    }

}

contract B { // A can make a B. A keeps track of B created, and B accepts param from A

    address private hub;
    address private owner;

    function B(address _owner) {
        hub = msg.sender; // A
        owner = _owner;
    }

    function getCreatedByHub() constant returns(address contractHub) {
        return hub;
    }

    function getContractOwner() constant returns(address contractOwner) {
        return owner; // owner of this contract
    }

    // this function just shows how B can fetch data from A if it needs to, such as a reference array or mapping
    function getAInfo(address contractAddress) constant returns(address owner) {
        address randomInquiryToA = A(hub).getContractOwner(contractAddress);
        return randomInquiryToA;
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.